# Як перекласти bullroarer?

Tags: переклад

Існує інструмент bullroarer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullroarer#Australian_Aboriginal_culture

На жаль, не зміг знайти взагалі жодних українських джерел про аборигенів Австралії, щоб хоча б пробувати шукати в тих джерелах...

На сторінці вікі навіть вказано фільм (Крокодил Данді 2), у якому він використовується, але, на жаль, він там не називається...

Comment: крутногуд чи крутноревун.

Answer (score 1):

Зустрїчає ся як запис через дефіс тут:

> <sub>[Англо-український словник](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/6/66/25638.html), Микола Іванович Балла</sub>
>
> **BULL-ROARER**
> *n* тріскачка, торохкало.

Але не знаю, наскільки пасують згадані слова, бо можуть перегукувати ся з гиншими приладами, втч. музичними.

> <sub>Вікіпедія</sub>
>
> [Трїскачка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F))
>
> - *Дерка́ч*, також відомий як *вертушка*, [*тріскачка*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87_(%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)) — народний шумовий інструмент з родини ідіофонів, де звук видобувають обертанням. Номер у класифікації Горнбостеля-Закса — 112.24
> - [*Тріскачка*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)) — народний музичний інструмент родини ідіофонів. Поширеній у російській народній музиці (рос. *трещотка*).
>
> Торохкало
>
> - *Калата́ло* ([…], розм. [*торохкало*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE) […]) — деревʼяний музичний інструмент родини ідіофонів. Складається з деревʼяної пластини з ручкою і одного чи кількох рухомих елементів, що під час різкого руху видають стук, калатання.

Answer (score 1):

Зрештою знайшов слово "**Фуркало**": [https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фуркалка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

(синоніми: Фу́ркало, фу́ркальце, фуркотало, ху́ркало, або дзижча́лка)

На сторінці вікі навіть йдеться про "Релігійні фуркали індіанського народу Апачі", зображення те ж саме, що на англійській вікі про bullroarer.

Також знайшов youtube відео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2p-cEgOykmM з назвою "Фуркало. Bullroarer", навіть звук дуже схожий на те, що почув у фільмі "Крокодил Данді 2".

СУМ, на жаль, дає значення (http://sum.in.ua/s/furkalo):

> Те саме, що дзиґа

Але приклади натякають на те, що значення значно ближче до bullroarer:

> А як почав акробат перекидатись на трапеції: то звисаючи головою вниз, то крутячись фуркалом на качалці

Підозрюю, акробат робив повні оберти на перекладені, а не крутився на місці, що більше б нагадувало дзиґу.